# Redux: Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using redux in my react app.

when I dispatch an action, this error occurs -

```
Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

this is my code  -

```
interface ChatProps extends ConnectedChatProps{
}
class ChatAppComponent extends Component<ChatProps> {
     render(){
        return(<p onClick={() => this.props.authenticated(this.props)}>Authenticayted: 
                   {''+this.props.isAuthenticated}</p> )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => {
    return { 
        isAuthenticated: state.shared.isAuthenticated
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Function) => ({ 
    authenticated: (props: ChatProps) =>  {        
        return dispatch(new AuthenticatedStateAction(!props.isAuthenticated));
    }
})
const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
type ConnectedChatProps = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;
export const ChatApp = connector(ChatAppComponent);

class AuthenticatedStateAction implements Action{
    type = 'Shared: SetAuthenticatedState Action';
    constructor(public payload: boolean){}
}
```

When I was using a plain object instead of `new AuthenticatedStateAction()`, the action was dispatching correctly. I have implemented the `Action` interface in the `AuthenticatedStateAction`. I don't know what is wrong with my implementation of the `Action` interface.

Can anyone look into this?

Comment: " I don't know what is wrong with my implementation" The problem is with the approach. Redux by design only accepts plain objects. If you want to dispatch some class instances you'd need to create a middleware that will take instances and convert them to plain objects before passing it down.

Comment: What is `Action`? What is the import path? (from what package or lib)

Comment: Action is imported from redux - 
`import { Action } from "redux";`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, How can I use middlewares in react? Do I need to create one? And How to configure these middlewares?

Comment: https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware You'd need to use one if you keep using classes instances as actions. More canonical approach would be to use factory functions (action creators) that produce plain objects to encapsulate action creation logic instead of a classes.